# Split A String On Certain Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, split

I had a requirement where I had to split a string having the following format:

```
1234-5678-91011_ABCD_EFGH
```

So I used the below code to make it work and it was done:

```
string str = "1234-5678-91011_ABCD_EFGH";
String[] parts = str.Split("_"); //Spliting The String Here
string part1 = "";
string part2 = "";
string part3 = "";

if (parts.Length > 2 && parts[2] != null)
{
   part1 = parts[0]; //Retrieves The First Part
   part2 = parts[1]; //Second Part
   part3 = parts[2]; //Third Part
}
```

So the final output is this: `1234-5678-91011 ABCD EFGH` where I require to get the first part with dashes. So pretty basic. Now the requirement is this: **1234-5678-91011-ABCD-EFGH** and where I've to retrieve this again - **1234-5678-91011**. This part could be anything, numbers or words. Any way that I can retrieve the first part with the new format?

**N.B**: Basically this thing comes **1234-5678-91011_ABCD_EFGH** from an anchor that's being concatenated with model properties. So by default,
it's like this:

```
1234 5678 91011
ABCD
EFGH

<a href="./@(item.Part1.Replace(" ", "-") + "_" + item.Part2 + "_" + item.Part3)">@item.Part1 @item.Part2 @item.Part3</a>
```

Clicking on the link will redirect me to another page where I require to get the first part or part1 value.

Comment: You could set any data format into your client side. Why it should be exactly manually created string but not json string format  for example ? You should not split string by condition in this case.

Comment: Will that be exact 13 digits or characters with group of 4, 4 and 5 separated by `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate three first entries then:

```
string[] parts = str.Split("-");
string part1 = "";
string part2 = "";
string part3 = "";

if(parts.Length > 4)
{
  part1 = $"{parts[0]}-{parts[1]}-{parts[2]}";
  part2 = parts[3];
  part2 = parts[4];
}
else if (parts.Length > 2)
{
  part1 = parts[0]; //Retrieves The First Part
  part2 = parts[1]; //Second Part
  part3 = parts[2]; //Third Part
}
```

after splitting received string by dash.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *match* with a help of *regular expressions*; if

> This part could be anything, *numbers or words*

means any word symbol we can use `\w`, if it can be an *arbitrary symbol* but `-`, then `[^-]` would do

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = "1234-5678-91011-ABCD-EFGH";

 // 1234-5678-91011
 string result = Regex.Match(source, @"\w+-\w+-\w+").Value;
```

You may want to have separate groups for parts:

```
 var match = Regex.Match(source, @"(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)");

 if (match.Success) {
    string part1 = match.Groups[1].Value; // "1234"
    string part2 = match.Groups[2].Value; // "5678"
    string part3 = match.Groups[3].Value; // "91011" 

    string all = match.Value;             // "1234-5678-91011"

    ... 
 }
```

Finally, if string must start from digit, add `^` to the pattern: `@"^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)"`

Comment: Please, note that "This part could be anything, numbers or words" - this refers to first three parts, so `[0-9]+` won't work for that.

Comment: @Michał Turczyn: Thank you! I see; so it could be either `\w`if "anything, numbers or words" means any word symbol or `[^-]` if it means arbitrary char but `-`

Comment: Correct :) Any character class `[...]+` not containing `-` is good solution here :) But I'd go for more restrictive `[a-z0-9]` with `i` flag, meaning case insensitivity :)